# Issue with geofence ENTER and EXIT

Tags: android

Am developing an android application where I need to create a Geofence and observe the ENTER and EXIT of the user in the Geofence. I was able to add the Geofences successfully, and written an Intent service class to handle the enter and exit transitions and generate a notification to the user. I Am generating the notification with the transition details which I am getting from the GeofencingEvent object.

When I am entering in the Geofence I am getting the transition details as "Uknown status Code: 1" and sometimes it's getting as SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED.

Please help me how to get proper transition details.

Answer (score 0):

SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED suggests that Play Services installed on your device are out of date and need to be updated. Try updating it via Google Play Store and try again.

Comment: Updated and getting the same message. i want this work on all the devices

Comment: Ok, but was there an update available and you installed it successfully? Are you sure that your app was properly reinitialized (reconnected) to Play Services after this update? To make sure, maybe try restarting the whole device.